# Spark SQL SELECT works but INSERT fails due to Spark issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

I am connecting to Iceberg running in Spark and querying tables. I am able to SELECT and INSERT from spark-shell. But face issues when executing the same statements from Java code

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("my app");
sparkConf.setMaster("spark://localhost:7077"); // my spark is running in k8s with port-forward
sparkConf.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false");
sparkConf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false");
...
// Bunch of Iceberg+Nessie related config properties
...

SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .config(sparkConf)
                .getOrCreate();
spark.sql("use my;"); // works
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my.table LIMIT 1;");  // works
spark.sql("INSERT INTO my.table (id, value) VALUES (1, 'test');")  // Does not work. see errors below
```

Here's what I see:

```
Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

But the error is misleading cuz there're enough resources.
I tried adding the `spark.driver.host` like so:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.host", "localhost");
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.port", "7077");
```

But this only results in the job exiting immediately and requesting a new worker.

How do I fix this so that I can run my query? Why is it only happening for INSERT queries?